# How to retrieve an Image in Bitmap format from the Media Library

Tags: c#, image, sitecore, sitecore7.2

I am performing image manipulation on Sitecore.

Given the ID of an image, I want to be able to retrieve it in Bitmap format - I am currently at loss on how to perform such an apparently simple task, and not for lack of searching.

EDIT: I am talking about a Bitmap object (System.Drawing.Bitmap), the reason being that I need to process them using a third-party graphic library (AForge).

Comment: Do you want to achieve that from the code?

Comment: Indeed - please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out eventually; this is the code that will convert an image residing in Sitecore's Media Library in System.Drawing.Bitmap format:

```
var item = new Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(imageId);
var mediaItem = Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem(item);
var image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(mediaItem.GetMediaStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `Bitmap` data from a `MediaItem` instance, you'll need to access the `Stream`, which can be done via `GetMediaStream()`.

This is a disposable resource, so `using` should be used.

`Bitmap` can then take the `Stream` as a parameter, but as `Bitmap` is *also* disposable, `using` should be used again:

```
var mediaItem = ...get the media from a field or database...
using (var stream = mediaItem.GetMediaStream())
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(stream))
{
  ...use the bitmap...
}
```